# Retrieving large image using facebookClient.Get with field full_picture

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have the following code:

```
dynamic feed = _facebookClient.Get(string.Format(appURL) + "?fields=message,picture,full_picture,link&limit=" + take);
```

The field "full_picture" is supposed to deliver a big picture, atleast from what i can read on the facebook graph explorer.

However, the result is a 130px picture, which isn't very large. The URL does differ from "picture", but is the same size.

Any suggestions? I've been googeling and trying lots of stuff, but i cant figure this out. If anyone has any resource where i can read, ill gladly find it myself.

I tried using the paramter ?size=large after picture, but that gives me a error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this is now working. I figure it had to be something wrong with the API at the time i was developing this project.

I uncommented my previous code, and it worked.

My code now look like this, if anyone is interested:

```
public class FacebookImpl
    {
        private static FacebookClient _facebookClient;

        public FacebookImpl()
        {
            const string appId = "my-app-id";
            const string appSecret = "my-secret";

            _facebookClient = new FacebookClient
            {
                AppId = appId,
                AppSecret = appSecret,
            };

            dynamic answer = _facebookClient.Get(string.Format("oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}", appId, appSecret));

            try
            {
                _facebookClient.AccessToken = answer.access_token;
            }
            catch (RuntimeBinderException)
            {
                // log
            }
        }

        public List<FacebookItem> GetWallFeed(int take, int skip)
        {

            const string appURL = "/MYFACEBOOKPAGE/posts";
            dynamic feed = _facebookClient.Get(string.Format(appURL) + "?fields=message,link,full_picture&limit=" + take, new { limit = take, offset = skip });

            var posts = new List<FacebookItem>();
            foreach (var item in feed.data)
        {
            posts.Add(new FacebookItem()
             {
                 Date = "Facebook " + DateTime.Parse(item.created_time).ToString("dd.MM"),
                 Title = item.message,
                 Url = item.link,
                 PhotoSrc = item.full_picture
             });
            return posts;
        }

            return posts;
        }
    }
```